# GPG sign Git commit on repository owned by root

Tags: linux, git, gnupg, gpg-agent

I have a Git repository owned by the root user that I can access with `sudo`. Normally in order to use this repo with Git, I use `sudo -E git ...`. The `-E` flag is necessary so that the Git within sudo inherits my default Git configuration such as author... etc.

I decided to try GPG signing of this repository, so I enabled the options.

```
> sudo -E git config user.email 'EMAIL' && sudo -E git config user.signingkey 'SIGNINGKEY' && sudo -E git config commit.gpgsign true && sudo -E git config tag.gpgsign true
```

However upon trying to do a commit:

```
> sudo -E git commit --allow-empty -m 'Test commit'

error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

However it does not appear that gpg can sign this repository with my GPG keys that exists in my user profile.

I've discovered new information about this problem: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/57779

Comment: It sounds like (to me) you are bringing problems upon yourself due to excessive use of `sudo`. Stop using `sudo` for daily tasks and many of your problems will go away. Delete the repo and start over. If you truly need to develop as root, then just `sudo su -` and be done with it (this would be a very unusual requirement, and I would expect there are procedural problems).

Comment: This is root level configuration managed by the root user, Git is just used to version control it.

Comment: Coincidentally, I just landed here from Google with the same question. NixOS is a good example as where it is common to edit a directory as root (the root configuration directory /etc/nixos)

Comment: @user196499 That's the reason for this question!

Comment: I've discovered that this problem is very nuanced: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/57779 It's both about using the right gpg-agent and also a tty ownership issue due to the pinentry problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

```sh
# Login as root.
$ sudo -i

# Set up .gitconfig and .gnupg.
% mv /root/.gitconfig /root/.gitconfig.orig
% mv /root/.gnupg /root/.gnupg.orig
% ln -s /home/$USER/.gitconfig /root/.gitconfig
% ln -s /home/$USER/.gnupg /root/.gnupg

# Ensure GPG uses given tty and ensure permissions.
% export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
% chown root $(tty)

# Simple test.
% killall gpg-agent
% echo "test" | gpg --clearsign
```

Ensure:

- `gpg --list-keys` includes the key you want to sign with.
- `root` has permissions for the given `$(tty)`.
- `echo "test" | gpg --clearsign` runs successfully.

---

If you also use **ssh keys**, a similar solution:

```sh
# Login as root.
$ sudo -i

# Set up .ssh.
# NOTE: we must copy these files for correct perms.
% mv /root/.ssh /root/.ssh.orig
% cp -r /home/$USER/.ssh /root/.ssh

# Do some remote action.
% git push
```